# gssapi error - Server not found in Kerberos database

Tags: c, kerberos, gssapi

I'm trying to write a kerberos aware application using the gssapi in c. I've been following the guides on [this site](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWdev/GSSAPIPG/p2.html#OVERVIEW-6), but I am getting stuck when calling `gss_import_name` with `HOST/SERVER-NAME` in my buffer..

I keep getting the error "Server not found in Kerberos database".

I'm trying to connect to a windows server from a linux box running Centos 6.5, using the preinstalled gssglue library. I followed [this guide](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/44885-setup-centos-to-authenticate-via-active-directory) to connect my linux box to the windows domain. In a nutshell, I ran `authconfig` with a bunch of commands and then `net ads join`. I can successfully call kinit with my windows domain password, so I know I am authenticating through the domain.

How do I add this server to my Kerberos database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, wether the SPN is really registered in the AD. Obviously it isn't, that's why it is failing. Edit: The formatted string you pass to `gss_import_name` is not correct. It does not look like with SSPI but it is different with GSS-API. Your call must look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181997/696632).

Comment: It works using the same principal name from windows to windows using the sspi. Does that necessarily mean the the SDN is registered?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would fail. Check the machine account. You might have a problem with reverse DNS also, because the default setting is to perform a reverse DNS lookup.

Comment: What do you mean by machine account? Also, I am able to do a reverse DNS lookup of the system I am trying to connect to, and from the system I am trying to connect to I can do a reverse DNS lookup of the connecting system.

Comment: Did you check the AD for that `servicePrincipalName` if you cannot find it, enquire with your admin, if you can find it, you must sniff the traffic with Wireshark to find the root cause. This is  what I am doing if in doubt.

Comment: Looking at the wireshark capture, It looks like my hostname is being added on to the end of the Kerberos TGS-REQ. It ends up sending HOST/{SERVER-NAME}.{MY-HOST-NAME}.{MY-DOMAIN}.org

Comment: where as the SPN should look like `host/fqdn@REALM`. The name you pass to `gss_import_name` is *not* correct. See edit of my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Changing it from HOST/SERVER-NAME to HOST@SERVER-NAME did the trick.